# Are the AWS Comprehend synchronous calls (e.g. BatchDetectSentiment) logged in Cloudtrail?

Tags: amazon-cloudtrail, amazon-comprehend

The AWS documentation explicitly list the API calls that are logged here: [Logging Amazon Comprehend API Calls with AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) and they seems not to be included, but at the same time there is an example here: [Logging Amazon Comprehend Medical API Calls by Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail2.html) that shows DetectEntities.

Answer (score 0):

Comprehend does log all synchronous requests to Cloudtrail. Thank you for bringing this to our attention. We are already aware of the issue and will be updating the documentation soon.

Edit - Documentation has been corrected to reflect all the APIs.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html